# Problem with Expresso or Rich Text fields inside a Matrix inside a Low Variable

Tags: matrix, expresso, low-variables, richtext, expresso-toolbar

I have a Low Variable that is set as a Matrix field. Inside of my Matrix, I have a field set as an Expresso field. When I view the edit variable screen, the Expresso toolbar doesn't show up -- the field just appears to be a regular text field.

When I try to display my Low Variable field in a template, it displays the Expresso text unprocessed, as if it were a regular text field, and I get these php errors:

```
Message: Undefined property: Expresso_ft::$row
Filename: expresso/ft.expresso.php
Line Number: 389

Message: Undefined property: Expresso_ft::$row
Filename: expresso/ft.expresso.php
Line Number: 390

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output     started at /path/to/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 412
```

I have the same issue if I switch the field type from Expresso to Rich Text -- no editing buttons on the edit variable screen, and these php errors:

```
Message: Undefined index: field_fmt
Filename: libraries/Rte_lib.php
Line Number: 505

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output     started at /path/to/system/codeigniter/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 412
```

I don't have any problems using Matrix, Expresso or Rich Text fields as Low Variables individually, it's only when I nest the Expresso or RT fields inside a Matrix inside of a Low Variable.

I'm running EE 2.5.4, Low Variables 2.3.2, Matrix 2.5.2 and Expresso 3.0.2

Comment: What version of Matrix?

Comment: @BrandonKelly Matrix 2.5.2. Sorry, thought I specified that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this problem also. The developer of Expresso has indicated that [this is not supported and might never be.](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/expresso/viewthread/6139#27588)

While I don't have a solution, I did some tests to see if any other "wysiwyg"-style fieldtypes support this. Here's what I found:

- Native RTE: No
- Expresso: No
- Wygwam: Yes
- Wyvern: Yes
- Redactee: Yes
- Editor (DevDemon): Yes

Answer (score 0):

/system/expressionengine/modules/rte/libraries/Rte_lib.php line 505

Instead of

if ($settings['field_fmt'] == 'xhtml')
                {
                    $this->EE->load->library('typography');

```
                $data = $this->EE->typography->_format_newlines($data);

                // Remove double paragraph tags
                $data = preg_replace("/(<\/?p>)\\1/is", "\\1", $data);
            }
```

you should check if isset this field. Like this.

if (isset($settings['field_fmt'])) {

```
            if ($settings['field_fmt'] == 'xhtml')
            {
                $this->EE->load->library('typography');

                $data = $this->EE->typography->_format_newlines($data);

                // Remove double paragraph tags
                $data = preg_replace("/(<\/?p>)\\1/is", "\\1", $data);
            }
        }
```